# Can't connect to MySQL database to Visual Studio?

Tags: mysql, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api, installation

I have a mysql database, I have to create asp.net web API that uses this API, but now I ma facing a problem connecting mySql to visual studio!

So I have installed *mysql for visual studio* **v1.2.9**, & *mysql for .NET* **v8.0.22**.

Then I moved to my Tools / Connect to Database, I selected MySQL Database, then I got this :

[image]

I know it said that there's an error in my installation is not set right, but why everything was working perfectly fine before trying this mysql thing !

Anyone has gone through such problem with mysql ?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is your VS version?

Comment: Visual Studio 2019

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is quite strange and when I install these two installation packages, I can open **MySQL Database** without any errors.

Open **VS2019**-->Click **Tools**-->**Connect to Database**-->select **MySQL Database**:

[image]

So please try the following steps to troubleshoot the issue:

=================================

**1)** disable any third party extensions under **Extensions**-->**Manage Extensions**-->**Installed**

**a) Then**, close VS, delete all cache files `C:\Users\xxx(current user)\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_xxx\ComponentModelCache`

**Note**: `16.xxx` is VS2019 and `15.xxx` is VS2017.

**b)** Open **Control Panel**-->**Programs**--> and find the two programs-->right-click on them-->**Repair**

**c) After that**, open VS and then test whether the issue occurs.

================================

**2)** If the step one does not work, I think you should restore vs to the original environment. Afterwards, uninstall the two programs.

**a)** Open VS-->**Tools**-->**Import and Export Settings**--> click **Reset all settings**

**b)** close VS, delete the whole vs setting folders under  `C:\Users\xxx(current user)\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_xxx`

**c)** install the two mysql programs and remember to click **Complete** mode to install the two programs.

**d)** when you finish it, try to test again.

================================

**3)** the third suggestion is to [repair VS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) or update the VS if there is a new release version.